# Call Mixin method when overriding

Tags: ember.js

I've got a Mixin in my controller that has a particular action. I need to override this action, do some stuff, and then call the original action provided by the Mixin.

How can I do this?

`this._super()` doesn't seem to work in this case (which does make sense, as it's meant to call the superclass' implementation, not a Mixin's).

Comment: isn't this http://emberjs.jsbin.com/docig/2/edit what you describe? `this._super()` seems to work ok unless i misunderstood

Comment: Yes! Strange that it seems to work there, but not in my app... @kingpin2k, how do you explain this?

Comment: i would advise to post some code maybe the structure/design of your objects cause this as a side effect.

Comment: I figured out what causes mine not to work. I'm calling `this._super()` wrapped in the `Ember.run.next` function, so that it runs on the next iteration of the runloop. This is precisely the reason I need to override the mixin method, so I can't get rid of this call. Any reason you can think of that would cause things to break, and if there is a workaround?

Comment: yes you can set the `this._super` to a variable and call that instead, i'll post it to make it clear.

Comment: yeah, i totally lied elsurudo, they must have changed that, at one point it didn't allow that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to call `this._super` from `Ember.run.next`  try the following,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/docig/3/edit

```
App.MyCustomMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
  testFunc:function(){
    alert('original mixin testFunc');
  },
  actions:{
    testAction:function(){
      alert('original mixin testAction');
    }
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend(App.MyCustomMixin,{
  testFunc:function(){
    alert('overriden mixin testFunc');

    var orig_func = this._super;
    Ember.run.next(function(){
      orig_func();
    });
  },
  actions:{
    test:function(){
      this.testFunc();
    },
    testAction:function(){
      alert('overriden mixin testAction');
      var orig_func = this._super;
      Ember.run.next(function(){
        orig_func();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm already using the variant of Ember.run.next that takes the scope as the first variable, and I pass `this`, as in `Ember.run.next(this, function() { this._super() })`, and it still isn't working. Any idea what could interfere with this?

Comment: @elsurudo does your system work if you avoid calling `this._super()` and call a variable set beforehand as shown in the answer? this approach works with `Ember.run.next(this,function(){....})` as well, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/docig/4/edit

Comment: @elsurudo well then there is probably something else, please post the code that is not working, if it is possible, so i can assist you further.

Comment: It seems this functionality doesn't work in the latest Ember Canary (which is what I'm using). See: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kudim/1/edit All I did was switch the ember version, and no-workie!